# Batch Scripting Syntax Error

Tags: scripting, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to built a simple dungeon crawler game with batch script, but I keep coming across the error as I'm creating the menu screen. Could anyone please help to point out what I'm going wrong? FIXED cheers guys :)

```
@echo off 
cls
echo LOADING GAME
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
@echo off
color 8a
title Josh's Game Beta

:loop 
:menu
cls 
echo You get to...
echo.
echo 1) Start
echo.
echo 2) Info
echo.
echo 3) Exit
set /p number = 

if not defined number (
cls
goto loop
)

if %number% == 1 goto game 
if %number% == 2 goto info 
if %number% == 3 exit

:game
cls
echo Who are you?
set /p name = 
echo Hello, %name% 
echo Do you want to start the game(Y/N)
set /p start =

if %start% == Y goto lvl1
if %start% == y goto lvl1
if %start% == N goto menu
if %start% == n goto menu 
if not defined start (
cls
goto menu 
)
```

Comment: Does the error contain a line number for the error? As an aside, I'd recommend a better language like python for this kind of program. http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: I believe the error is something to do with the syntax, Dan. I dont have enough time to take a good look before it closes off :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked for other problems, but the following statement is creating a variable named "number " (with a space at the end):

```
set /p number =
```

The correct syntax would be

```
set /p "number="
```

Comment: Cheers guys, and I use java and python on a daily basis hahah :P But I am still having the same problem :(

Comment: @JoshLewis - Why don't you tell us what error or problem you are having (edit your question). BTW, the problem I pointed out and fixed in my answer is real :-)

Comment: Yeah no I believe you completely, I just started this today and I ran into some problems but I cant really explain any other way.